# How can I prevent (not react to) a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, linux, macos, segmentation-fault

I am not trying to handle a segmentation fault.  I understand how exception handling works, more or less. I would rather not have the fault in the first place.  What I want to do is call a function or perform an operation that returns a value telling me whether or not that particular memory location/block is accessible, without actually accessing it and getting the fault.

That is, I would like a C function to probe an address in Linux and/or Mac OS X before actually accessing it.  Something like:

```
result = probe_memory(address,length)
```

where result is

```
 0 = writable
 1 = read-only
-1 = nonexistent
```

or something along those lines.

Is there anything like that in Linux and/or Mac OS X?

Comment: Feel up to parsing the TLBs?

Comment: It depends.  Would it be system dependent?  I was hoping for something that would work on both platforms.  Really, I'm surprised that such a thing isn't included in the standard library.  Prevention is always better than recovery.

Comment: Prevention, in this case, is also an awful lot of work.

Comment: Good luck handling a segfault even if you wanted to.

Comment: For dynamically allocated memory (allocated via `malloc()` et al), consider the techniques described in [Writing Solid Code](http://www.amazon.com/Writing-Solid-Microsoft-Programming-Series/dp/1556155514) by Steve Maguire.  (Also be aware that there are those vehemently opposed to anything the books says — you can find such reviews at the [ACCU](http://www.accu.org/) web site, amongst other places.)

Comment: On Linux you might be able to pull some information out of `/proc/self/maps`, but if this is for something other than just curiosity's sake... you're probably doing something wrong if you need to ask whether an address is valid.

Comment: Of course you are doing something wrong.  This is intended for library routines that are called from many different programs, including code still under development.  But just in case something isn't caught before it goes into production, I'd rather do the error checking up front rather than dying and picking up the pieces after the fact.

Comment: Would a signal handler work?

Comment: @user157426: What about using something like valgrind then? This actually will catch more difficult to find errors -- like memory corruption that *doesn't* cause a seg fault.

Comment: Yes, that looks like the type of thing I am looking for.  I asked for a routine, but a package works too.  It appears to be available for linux and mac, which is what I need.  I can give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

I believe something more or less like the following should work:

```
int probe_memory(void *address, size_t length) {
    int result, fd[2];

    pipe(fd);  /* Remember to check for errors! */

    errno = 0;
    result = write(fd[1], address, length);

    if (result < 0 || (size_t)result != length || errno == EFAULT) {
        result = 0;
    } else {
        result = 1;
    }

    close(fd[0]);
    close(fd[1]);

    return result;
}
```

> **This is a partial solution to your problem, as this code does not check for page protection.**

The basic idea is to let the OS read `length` bytes from `address` through the call to `write`. If the memory is not accessible, it will return `EFAULT` without triggering a segfault.

[Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) wrote a fully worked up implementation in his [Stack Overflow Questions repository](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/so-1886-3184).

Comment: I really need the page protection part.  I should have emphasized that more.  The reason it came up was because I have a function that receives a string as a parameter and may make modifications to it. But one caller passed a canned string (char canned[] = "hard-coded string";) and I got a seg fault.  If I know that it's read only I can allocate a string, copy, and modify the copy.

Comment: Why not just have the caller provide a writable byte buffer as a parameter?  If speed is such a concern that you're reluctant to always allocate a writable copy yourself, then why take the time to probe the string?

Comment: Interesting idea; it is expensive, and needs some tweaking, but it does work.  The tweaking is in the error detection; that should be: `errno = 0; result = write(fd[1], address, length); if (result < 0 || (size_t)result != length || errno == EFAULT) result = 0; else result = 1;`.  This punts the problem to the kernel.  For practical code, you'd have to keep the pipe open (one call to `pipe()` and two calls to `close()` is very expensive), but you also have to worry about the length of the pipe buffer (8 KiB on Mac OS X) and the value in `length` (longer than 8 KiB will jam your program).

Comment: Thank you @Jonathan for figuring out the correct error detection, added to the post.

Comment: You can find worked up code based on the ideas in this answer available on GitHub in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository as files `memprobe.c` and `memprobe.h` in the [src/so-1886-3184](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/so-1886-3184) sub-directory.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [mincore(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mincore.2.html) and you could read sequentially and parse `/proc/self/maps`, see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

Notice that Linux is not designed to give such mapping information quickly. It is well known that emulating application paging (like GNU/Hurd external pagers...) is slow. (e.g. by some low-level, processor specific, `SIGSEGV` handler).

If your only purpose is to give backtrace information on `SIGSEGV`, you could use Ian Taylor's [libbacktrace](https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/tree/master/libbacktrace) from GCC source code.

As some comments said, perhaps you want [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot in your list of responses - writeable but in use by the OS/something critical/is actually memory mapped self destruct, etc.

Your best bet is to try to make you code bullet proof a part of which is you **only** write to locations that **you** own.

An allocate, check, copy, modify will probably end up being quicker, more reliable, portable and more maintainable that trying to twist the OS(es) arm into giving the information needed and much more so than trying to check it yourself.