# C test if variable is in read-only section

Tags: c, gcc, macros

I'd like to write a low-level logging function that would look like:

```
DO_DBG("some string", val1, val2)
```

What I want it to do, is to store the pointer to the string rather than a copy of the string, for performance reasons.   This assumes that the string is a read-only literal.   To prevent people having to debug the debugger, it would be nice if the compiler could complain if the first parameter of `DO_DBG` was in a writable section of code vs text, etc.  I'm wondering if a mechanism to do that exists.  (I'm using gcc 4.9.1, ld 2.24).

Comment: If an arbitrary **variable** or a **string literal** is read-only? The C standard guarantees string literals to be read-only. However, it is implementation-defined if equal strings are stored at the same address.

Comment: Yes, but I want the compiler to fail compilation if someone tries to pass anything but a string literal as the first parameter of the function.   The function would take a `const char *` parameter, and I want to know if it's a literal...

Comment: That seems like circumventing undefined behavior and replacing it with something "more secure" such as compile time errors. I don't think it's possible without modifying the compiler/breaking the C standard.

Comment: Your function will get passed a pointer whether the parameter is a string literal or an array.  Unless you have concerns about concurrent modification, I'm not sure I see the benefit.

Comment: @cad the standard doesn't guarantee string literals are read-only, it says writing them has undefined effects

Comment: @dbush Imagine that DO_DBG just stores what it is passed in some structure and then later if "bad thing" happens, the contents get read out/printed out of it.

Comment: Is there even the notion of a "writable section of code" at the *compile* stage?

Comment: It depends how desperate you are.  Take a look at the answer to [How can I prevent (not react to) a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18863184/how-can-i-prevent-not-react-to-a-segmentation-fault)  You might be able to adapt that by, for example, writing one byte from your string to the pipe and then reading it back from the pipe — the read should fail (probably with EFAULT) if your memory is not writable.  OTOH, my testing was not definitive — it didn't work as I hoped, but I was lying to the compiler so it was getting its own back by making my `const` array non-const.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the automatic literal string concatenation to your advantage:

```
#define DO_DBG(s, a, b) _DO_DBG("" s, a, b)
```

And implement your real macro as `_DO_DBG`.

Comment: @KerrekSB - then the required compile time error will be raised.

Comment: Awesome -- that will do exactly what I want.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a `SIGSEGV` handler, and then try to do:

```
s[0] = s[0];
```

If the handler is triggered, it means that the variable is in a read-only segment, so you can save the pointer. If not, you can complain (or just make a copy of the string).

You'll need to declare the string `volatile` so the compiler doesn't optimize the assignment away.

Comment: That would work for run time, but OP is looking for a compile time check.

Comment: Ahh, didn't realize that. He talked about read-only and writable memory areas, which seems like a runtime issue.

Comment: It is an interesting approach to testing read-only though.  It might be useful in something else down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use the stringify macro construct:

```
#define DO_DBG(s, a, b) DO_DBG_INTERNAL(# s, a, b)
```

and call your function `DO_DGB_INTERNAL`
so people would do:

```
DO_DBG(some string, val1, val2)
```

PS, quite possibly a variadic function and macro would be a good idea here.

Comment: The result of stringification is again a constant string, which will be handled just like a string written out in longhand by the programmer. This shouldn't make an iota of difference.

Comment: If you do: `DO_DBG(some_charstar_var, ...)` you will definitely avoid the problem of the value of `some_charstar_var` changing affecting what DO_DBG stored away...

Comment: Not at all. The varargs handling is entirely at runtime.

Comment: You have completely missed the point.  The OP is concerned with `char * c;` (c points to some string) `DO_DBG(c, etc)` `DO_DEBUG saves the value of c` (c points to some other string) (the value DO_DBG saved is accessed, but may be invalid or changed since the call to DO_DBG).

Comment: OP is worried that somehow `"this is a constant string"` gets mangled, that I get. It *can't* be mangled in legal C. And there is no (even remotely sane) way to find out if what you got is a pointer to a constant string or an array changed elsewhere. Don't do it, or stash the argument away. Going to all this contortions for *scaffolding* to help *debugging* is just insane, better spend that effort on doing it right in the first place.

Comment: It sounds like he is developing a debugging facility that others will use and is trying to make it as foolproof as possible, which I applaud -- although there is some truth to the aphorism that it only produces greater fools.

Answer (score 0):

Your function gets a pointer to the start of the string. If your operating system allows it, and the compiler sets it up that way, a constant string (like in your example) could be allocated in a read-only memory area. If your compiler is smart, it will store one copy of a string constant that appears several times. It might even figure out that some strings are never used, and just not store them at all.

Other than the above, unless your program relies on undefined behaviour (getting away with writing on a constant string), you should not be able to figure out if it is in read-only memory or not. You could compare addresses of strings to see if they are only one copy, but that is it.

In any *reasonable* C implementation (i.e., one that doesn't go out of its's way just to screw you over), you will see no (or at most an extremely small) performance difference if the string is read-only, read-write, one copy or several.

If you write you function with a `char *` parameter, and store said pointer away (not a copy to the string pointed to), you *should* always get the same string back (unless your environment is really strange).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a SIGSEGV-handler-based test to check if pointed-at memory is mapped read-only:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

static sigjmp_buf label;
static void segv_hndlr(int Sig) { siglongjmp(label,1); } //safe in this ctx
_Bool is_ro(char volatile *X)
{
    _Bool r=0;
    struct sigaction old;
    X[0]; //fault now if the target isn't writable
    if(sigsetjmp(label,1))
        { r=1; goto out; }
    sigaction(SIGSEGV,&(struct sigaction){.sa_handler=segv_hndlr}, &old);
    X[0]=X[0];
out: sigaction(SIGSEGV,&old, NULL);
    return r;
}

//example:
int main()
{
    #define PR_BOOL(X) printf(#X"=%d\n", X)
    char bar[]="bar";
    char *baz = strdup("baz");
    static int const static_ro_int = 42;
    int const auto_ro_int = 42;
    PR_BOOL(is_ro("foo")); //1
    PR_BOOL(is_ro(bar)); //0
    PR_BOOL(is_ro(baz)); //0
    PR_BOOL(is_ro((void*)&static_ro_int)); //1
    PR_BOOL(is_ro((void*)&auto_ro_int)); //0
}
```