# check string lifetime duration

Tags: c, string, lifetime

I am currently wondering if it is possible to check if a C-string has a static lifetime duration or not when only the pointer to the string is known.

Basically, I want to implement such a function:

```
bool isStaticString(const char *str)
{
    //do magic stuff
}
```

and the results should be like this:

```
 isStaticString("Hello World!"); //returns true

 char str[5] = {'\0'};
 isStaticString(str); //returns false
```

Is there any portable way to implement such a function?

PS: I hope such question was not already asked,I did not really know what to search for. My title did not give me any results.

Comment: No, and why do you need this?

Comment: Are you asking about C or C++?

Comment: Writing to a string in read-only memory should throw an exception, which you can catch and ignore (I think). But the compiler won't compile it because your string is declared `const` and so you'll have to override that in turn. It is also not *portable*: it depends on the target OS being able to construct read-only segments, and the compiler writing such strings into one.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: writing into the string will trigger a fault if it's inside read-only memory. AFAIK both languages C and C++ themselves have no meta-information about strings (or other information), other than that they can be declared `const` or not. Which (again AFAIK) you cannot *test* in run-time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C test if variable is in read-only section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093205/c-test-if-variable-is-in-read-only-section)

Comment: @PaulAnkman Read-onlyness and static storage are orthogonal. `static char foo[123];` is static but perfectly mutable.

Comment: What you could do is comparing the pointer with beginning of the `.data` section of your binary should do the trick. However doing so is not portable and ill-advised.

Comment: To me it looks like you are really asking how to determine if a string is a read only string literal.  In C/C++ static means globally scoped in the data segment... not on the stack.   Static variables can still be modified.

Comment: Testing if it's mapped read-only  is doable (wrote an answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093205/c-test-if-variable-is-in-read-only-section), but e.g., on posix platforms you cannot easily distinguish between a page mmaped by the loader/linker and a page mmapped by user code. From the point of view of pure ISO C -- definitely impossible.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to do in a portable or reliable way.

However, pointers to static and read-only memory will typically be in a different memory segments than stack and dynamically-allocated memory, so you can check the difference between your pointer and some pre-allocated sample pointer, and kind of guess the memory layout.

```
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

enum { CHAR_ARRAY_SIZE = 32 }; // Say no to magic constants

const char readonlyFossilizedBirdBones[CHAR_ARRAY_SIZE] = "Crow skeleton from taxidermist";
char globalVariableBirdBones[CHAR_ARRAY_SIZE] = "This pigeon was hit by a car";

bool askBirdBonesIfStringIsStatic(const char *str)
{
    char freshStackBirdBones[CHAR_ARRAY_SIZE] = "Chicken wings from trash bin";
    char * bloodyAllocBirdBones = (char *) malloc(CHAR_ARRAY_SIZE);
    // strcpy() is unsafe, and strncpy() does not always zero-terminate the result
    // but snprintf() is safe and will not trigger any static code analysis tools
    snprintf(bloodyAllocBirdBones, CHAR_ARRAY_SIZE, "%s", "Sparrow caught by your cat");
    bool divinationSaysStatic =
        abs(readonlyFossilizedBirdBones - str) < abs(freshStackBirdBones - str) &&
        abs(readonlyFossilizedBirdBones - str) < abs(bloodyAllocBirdBones - str) &&
        abs(globalVariableBirdBones - str) < abs(freshStackBirdBones - str) &&
        abs(globalVariableBirdBones - str) < abs(bloodyAllocBirdBones - str);
    printf("Asking bird bones about '%s' at %p:\n", str, str);
    printf("Comparing to readonly %p global %p stack %p alloc %p\n",
            readonlyFossilizedBirdBones, globalVariableBirdBones,
            freshStackBirdBones, bloodyAllocBirdBones);
    printf("Result is %s\n\n", divinationSaysStatic ? "favorable" : "unfavorable");
    free(bloodyAllocBirdBones);
    return divinationSaysStatic;
}

int main()
{
    static char s1[CHAR_ARRAY_SIZE] = "Static string";
    char s2[CHAR_ARRAY_SIZE] = "Short-lived stack string";
    char * s3 = (char *) malloc(CHAR_ARRAY_SIZE);
    snprintf(s3, CHAR_ARRAY_SIZE, "%s", "String allocated by malloc()");
    askBirdBonesIfStringIsStatic(s1);
    askBirdBonesIfStringIsStatic(s2);
    askBirdBonesIfStringIsStatic(s3);
    free(s3);
    return 0;
}
```

And the results on my 64-bit Linux PC:

```
Asking bird bones about 'Static string' at 0x560815f27080:
Comparing to readonly 0x560815d26b00 global 0x560815f27060 stack 0x7ffe741d0b90 alloc 0x560816365c50
Result is favorable

Asking bird bones about 'Short-lived stack string' at 0x7ffe741d0be0:
Comparing to readonly 0x560815d26b00 global 0x560815f27060 stack 0x7ffe741d0b90 alloc 0x560816365c50
Result is unfavorable

Asking bird bones about 'String allocated by malloc()' at 0x560816365c20:
Comparing to readonly 0x560815d26b00 global 0x560815f27060 stack 0x7ffe741d0b90 alloc 0x560816365c50
Result is unfavorable
```

Please never ever use this code in production.

Comment: Why convert the `readonlyFossilizedBirdBones - str` difference  to `int` with `abs()`.  It seems `imaxabs()` would be most likely to avoid signed integer overflow and/or truncation.