# Litmus test for checking if address range is in process address space?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, segmentation-fault, posix

I am wondering if there is any simple/neat way in C to detect if a given memory range `(A, A+len)` falls under the process address space?

**EDIT**:
My use case is more for reverse engineering and locating some strings (or fixed sized structs) in memory. So even a hacky test will work right for me to narrow down my search.

Comment: XY problem. Don't invoke undefined behaviour. There is no guarantee wrong memory accesses generate a signal.

Comment: If you think your program is accessing memory it shouldn't, run it under [valgrind](http://valgrind.org).  That will tell you where you're going wrong.

Comment: Let's back up a second: Why do you need to know? Generally speaking, you shouldn't ever end up with invalid pointers in the first place.

Comment: My use case is for reverse engineering and locate some strings (or fixed sized structs) in memory. So even a hacky test will work right for me to narrow down my search

Comment: See [How can I prevent (not react to) a segmentation fault?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18863184) for one way to do it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Indeed what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, read `/proc/$pid/maps`. It contains a textual description of the memory ranges mapped by a process, e.g.

```
00400000-0040b000 r-xp 00000000 08:00 35402                              /bin/cat
0060a000-0060b000 r--p 0000a000 08:00 35402                              /bin/cat
0060b000-0060c000 rw-p 0000b000 08:00 35402                              /bin/cat
006ab000-006cc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f9a73235000-7f9a734fe000 r--p 00000000 08:00 949                        /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7f9a734fe000-7f9a736b8000 r-xp 00000000 08:00 18124                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7f9a736b8000-7f9a738b8000 ---p 001ba000 08:00 18124                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7f9a738b8000-7f9a738bc000 r--p 001ba000 08:00 18124                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7f9a738bc000-7f9a738be000 rw-p 001be000 08:00 18124                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7f9a738be000-7f9a738c3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f9a738c3000-7f9a738e6000 r-xp 00000000 08:00 17952                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7f9a73ad9000-7f9a73adc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f9a73ae3000-7f9a73ae5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f9a73ae5000-7f9a73ae6000 r--p 00022000 08:00 17952                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7f9a73ae6000-7f9a73ae7000 rw-p 00023000 08:00 17952                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7f9a73ae7000-7f9a73ae8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffde1b80000-7ffde1ba1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffde1bd5000-7ffde1bd7000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffde1bd7000-7ffde1bd9000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

There's a lot of information here, but what matters to you is the first two columns. The first one is an address range, and the second one is the access privileges it's mapped with.

Note that this has a distinct advantage over any approach based around triggering segfaults: it can be read from another process, and doesn't require any code to be added to the target process.

Comment: But my use case is more from a C code. I will figure out a way to read from procmap. `Libproc` helps?